# Value in subscribe not updated if extender is used

Tags: knockout.js

I have called extender on a observable and have a rounding logic in it, and also have business logic in its subscribe. Problem is when a value of that observable is changed, first extender is called and value is changed (but not updated in the view). Meanwhile subscribe is called and if the value of the same observable is changed in subscribe, which is the latest change, but it's not set to the observable.

```
ko.extenders.scale = function(target, precision) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read:target,
        write:function(newValue) {
            var that = target;
            if (newValue)
                roundoff(that, precision, newValue);
        }
    }).extend({notify : 'always'});
    result(target());
    return result;
};

self.qty = ko.observable(0).extend({scale:2});

self.qty.subscribe(function() {
    if (self.qty() > self.availQty()) {
        self.qty(0); // This change in not reflected in the view
    }
});

var roundoff = function (targetValue,prec,newValue){
            var current = targetValue(),
            that = targetValue,
            valueToWrite = newValue;
            valueToWrite = isNaN(newValue)?0:parseFloat(+newValue).toFixed(prec);                                                          
            //toFixed may be replaced with other logic in future
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                that(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    that.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to get an answer, make a concrete question, show the observables and extenders code, and the bindings. If not, don't expect to get an answer. I've required to close this question because of "unclear what you're asking". I can assure KO can perfectly do what you need.

Comment: What does `roundoff` do? Can you include the code for that?

Comment: @MichaelBest, roundoff at present does toFixed, it may be extended,so this was created..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a subscribe/extender to do all this, you should perhaps just use a writeable computed. I've simplified your 'scale' example for simplicity just using toFixed... just plugin your own logic there.

**Fiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/fnj27bjj/

**HTML:**

```
<input id="qty" data-bind="value: quantityDisplay">
```

**JS**

```
var vm = function() {
    var self = this; 
    self.qty= ko.observable(0).extend({scale:2});
    self.availQty = ko.observable(10);
    self.quantity = ko.observable(0);
    self.quantityDisplay = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return parseFloat(self.quantity()).toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function(newValue){
            console.log(newValue);
            if(newValue > self.availQty()){
                    console.log("going zero");
                    self.quantity(0.00);
                }
            else {
                self.quantity(newValue);
            }
        },
        owner: self
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have code to update the value,

```
self.qty(0); // This change in not reflected in the view
```

that isn't updating the view. That's because you also have code to translate the update

```
write:function(newValue) {
    var that = target;
    if (newValue)
        roundoff(that, precision, newValue);
}
```

that doesn't update the observable if `newValue` is "falsy", which `0` is.

So you just need to change the `write` function to this:

```
write:function(newValue) {
    roundoff(target, precision, newValue);
}
```